# Application fails with OutOfMemoryError in CloudFoundry

Tags: java, out-of-memory, cloud-foundry, heap-dump

I have application deployed to Cloud Foundry. It used to work fine with 1Gb of heap space under java7 with java buildpack v2.4  But after upgrade to java8 buildpack v3.3.1 it began crashing with OutOfMemoryError from time to time. Even increasing max heap size up to 2GB didn't help. I need to find out the reason why it happens.

I am very new to Cloud Foundry and I am wondering how to get heap dump from application deployed to CF. Could you advise on this? Or maybe you have some thoughts why changing buildpack might cause such issues?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the MaxMetaspaceSize settings:

" In JDK 8, the permanent generation was removed and the class metadata is allocated in native memory. The amount of native memory that can be used for class metadata is by default unlimited. Use the option MaxMetaspaceSize to put an upper limit on the amount of native memory used for class metadata." [from Oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html)

As described in the "Allocate Sufficient Memory
" section of [Cloud Foundry Docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-tips.html) , a custom buildpack might be needed to customize these parameters

"To configure memory-related JRE options for your app, you create a custom buildpack and specify this buildpack in your deployment manifest. For more information about configuring custom buildpacks and manifests, refer to the Custom Buildpacks and Deploying with Application Manifests topics."

Hope that points you in the right direction.